# #I whish I could remember pi

Tags: python, windows, numpy, jupyter-lab

I tried running a loop to estimate pi. this is using a geometrical estimation by Archimedes stating the perimeter of any (convex) polygon inscribed in a circle is less than the circumference of the circle, which, in turn, is less than the perimeter of any circumscribed polygon.
the code goes like this:

```
import numpy as np
D = 1
n = 100
beta = np.deg2rad(360/n) # this is a bit of a cheat by go with me
S1 = n * D * np.sin(beta/2)
S2 = n * D * np.tan(beta/2)
print(f'{n=}, {S1=}, {S2=} , Error: {S2-S1}')
```

I get:
n=100, S1=3.141075907812829, S2=3.142626604335115 , Error: 0.0015506965222860103
all is good

now I tried to find **n** for a specific accuracy using a loop like this :

```
import numpy as np
D = 1
n = 10.0
beta = np.deg2rad(360/n) 
S1 = 2
S2 = 5
                    
while np.abs(S2-S1) > 1e-6:
    S1 = n * D * np.sin(beta/2)
    S2 = n * D * np.tan(beta/2)
    n *= 10
```

and I get:

n=inf, S1=inf, S2=inf , Error: nan

and an error message:
invalid value encountered in double_scalars
while np.abs(S2-S1) > 1e-6:

HELP , am I doing something wrong?

I am using python 3.9.6 on a window 10 and JupyterLab version 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to update `beta`, it should be done in the loop as `n` changes for each iteration:

```
import numpy as np
D = 1
n = 10.0
S1 = 2
S2 = 5
                    
while np.abs(S2-S1) > 1e-6:
    beta = np.deg2rad(360/n)
    S1 = n * D * np.sin(beta/2)
    S2 = n * D * np.tan(beta/2)
    n *= 10
```

Comment: wow thx a lot , this was a quick catch